# HAR parser and reporting tool

Tags: http, har

Is there any parser tool for HAR(Http archive) which generates csv or excel output of page loading times? I know there are HAR viewer but I need the output as csv for plotting.

Note: It is easier to write a parser and generate the csv output(which I have done) but before reinventing the wheel, I just want to check for existing tools.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you got the **har2csv** (command line tool), [here](https://github.com/danstuken/har2csv), and you can pull the zip file [here](https://github.com/danstuken/har2csv/downloads).